# Increased memory usage for both IOS and Android in react-navigation nested routes

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I have a deeply nested route as shown below.

```
const ReturnFlows = createStackNavigator(
  {
    OrderSelectScreen,
    ItemTBScreen,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'OrderSelectScreen'
  },
);
const CheckoutFlows = createStackNavigator(
  {
    ReviewScreen,
    CheckoutScreen,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'ReviewScreen'
  },
);

const ItemFlowScreens = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    ItemTAScreen,
    ReturnFlows,
    CheckoutFlows,
    CompletedScreen,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'CheckoutFlows',
  },
);

const CreateOrderScreens = createStackNavigator(
  {
    CustomerScreen,
    CSelectedScreen,
    WarehouseScreen,
    WSelectedScreen,
    ItemFlowScreens,
  },
  {
    headerMode: 'none',
  },
);

const Main = createStackNavigator(
  {
    ...otherRoutes,
    CreateOrderScreens,
    HomeScreen,
  },
  {
    headerMode: 'none',
  },
);
```

The Routes above roughly translate to the diagram below

[image: nav in image form]

Everything works fine but while I go deeper into the nested screens I noticed the memory usage spikes to 300mb. Additionally in the final `CompletedScreen`I have the following function to jump back to the initial home page.

```
const goHome = () => {
  _navigator.dispatch(
    StackActions.reset({
      key: null,
      index: 0,
      actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'HomeScreen' })],
    }),
  );
};
```

Even though i have enabled `useScreens` from `react-native-screens`and have jumped to the initial screen the memory usage does not seem go down. How can I overcome this issue ?